# Android - Stop Dialing on tapping HTML 

Tags: android, html, phone-call, dialing

I have create an Android application, in which I have use an HTML calendar. In device Motorola Droid X2, when user select date, the dialer is come and making the call. I need to restrict it.

Whether I have not use any code for dialing(Like:tel,url:tel).

Comment: Picture and code would help us understand what you are asking.

Comment: Actually I am getting dialer only in device "Motorola Droid X2".

Answer (score 0):

Try to owerride `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` methot in WebViewClient

example:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url){
        super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading view, url);
    }
}
```

Or some other code you want in this method